# Issue regarding XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to transform an XML of the following :

```
<entities xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><entityIds>
137651b03d18c0efee947f8bda341fb1
</entityIds>
<entityIds>
aa88ce76d454a0135c89bfbd4def62cd
</entityIds>
</entities>
```

using  XSL of following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<urlDetails>
<customerId>

<xsl:value-of select="//p:entityList/p:entity[1]/p:customerId" />
</customerId>
<entityIds>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
<xsl:for-each select="//p:entityList/p:entity">

<xsl:value-of select="p:entityId" />,
</xsl:for-each>
</entityIds>
</urlDetails>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

An I am getting an ouput like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlDetails xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
<customerId/>
<entityIds>
137651b03d18c0efee947f8bda341fb1
aa88ce76d454a0135c89bfbd4def62cd
</entityIds>
</urlDetails>
```

How can I make the ouput in comma seperated one like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <urlDetails xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <customerId/>
    <entityIds>
    137651b03d18c0efee947f8bda341fb1 ,
    aa88ce76d454a0135c89bfbd4def62cd
    </entityIds>
    </urlDetails>
```

I have used the string concat and using version2.0 I have use the value seperator,both are not working.Is there anyother techniques prefered?

Comment: Well the input sample you have posted as elements named `entities` and `entityIds`, yet your XPath expressions look like `//p:entityList/p:entity` and `p:entityId`. So none of the elements names in the path expression match the exact element names in the sample you have posted.

Comment: For which reason, I am downvoting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//p:entityList/p:entity">
  <xsl:value-of select="p:entityId" /><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 you should be able to drop the `for-each` (i.e. pass the whole node *set* to `value-of`) and use `separator`, e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="//p:entityList/p:entity/p:entityId" separator=","/>
```

For 1.0 `value-of` only handles one node at a time, so you need the for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//p:entityList/p:entity/p:entityId">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">,</xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

The `if` ensures you don't add an extra comma before the *first* item in the list.